# How to validate a form with multiple checkboxes to have atleast one checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a form using the validate plugin for jquery.  I want to require that  the user check at least one checkbox in a group in order for the form to be submitted.  Here's my jquery code:

```
$().ready(function() {
$("#subscribeForm").validate({
   rules:   { list: {required: "#list0:checked"} },
   messages:  { list:  "Please select at least one newsletter"}                                                        
 });
 });
```

and here's the html form:

```
<form action="" method="GET" id="subscribeForm">
<fieldset id="cbgroup">
    <div><input name="list" id="list0" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter0" >zero</div>
    <div><input name="list" id="list1" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter1" >one</div>
    <div><input name="list" id="list2" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter2" >two</div>
</fieldset>
<input name="submit" type="submit"  value="submit">
```

The problem is that the form submits even if nothing is checked.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: shouldn't your name elements be an array in the form of name="list[]" anyway?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This script below should put you on the right track perhaps?

You can keep this html the same (though I changed the method to POST):

```
<form method="POST" id="subscribeForm">
    <fieldset id="cbgroup">
        <div><input name="list" id="list0" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter0" >zero</div>
        <div><input name="list" id="list1" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter1" >one</div>
        <div><input name="list" id="list2" type="checkbox"  value="newsletter2" >two</div>
    </fieldset>
    <input name="submit" type="submit"  value="submit">
</form>
```

and this javascript validates

```
function onSubmit() 
{ 
    var fields = $("input[name='list']").serializeArray(); 
    if (fields.length === 0) 
    { 
        alert('nothing selected'); 
        // cancel submit
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        alert(fields.length + " items selected"); 
    }
}

// register event on form, not submit button
$('#subscribeForm').submit(onSubmit)
```

and you can find a [working example of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/evildonald/qsBKy/1/)

**UPDATE (Oct 2012)**
Additionally it should be noted that the checkboxes *must* have a "name" property, or else they will not be added to the array. Only having "id" will not work.

**UPDATE (May 2013)**
Moved the submit registration to javascript and registered the submit onto the form (as it should have been originally)

**UPDATE (June 2016)**
Changes == to ===

Comment: Why use `onsubmit` (on the button instead of the form, no less!) instead of `$('form').submit(function() {...})`?

Comment: Er, should be `$('#subscribeForm').submit(...)`

Comment: This works, but as I should have made more clear in my original question, I'm trying to use the validate plugin because the actual form is more complex and I'm trying to validate a bunch of other stuff.  The other fields are validating just fine; it's just the checkbox group that's problematic.  So, really, my question is whether I can get the validate plugin to do something like this.

Comment: Ah, I think I've got it working by substituting "input[name='list']" in the "required: " rules parameter.  So, my jquery "rule" now looks like this:
rules:  { list: {required: "input[name='list']", minlength: 1} },

Comment: Should change fields.length == 0 to fields.length === 0.

Answer (score 52):

```
  $('#subscribeForm').validate( {
      rules: {
          list: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 1
          }
       }
   });
```

I think this will make sure at least one is checked.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I add this rule, other rules don't work as expected. Such as, I have "rule1" for textbox and "rule2" for list checkbox. If "rule2" is satisfied, the form submit no matter what "rule1" is. On the other hand, if "rule2" is not satisfied, it reports the error of "rule2". If both are not satisfied, both errors are reported.

Comment: I think 'required' is sufficient (not sure whether minlength is also necessary).  You might want to put it in the js, but just adding the required attribute to the inputs themselves will also accomplish the task.

Answer (score 14):

How about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subscribeForm').submit(function() {
        var $fields = $(this).find('input[name="list"]:checked');
        if (!$fields.length) {
            alert('You must check at least one box!');
            return false; // The form will *not* submit
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is a very smooth and fast way, I like it!

Comment: But makes no use of the jQuery Validate plugin as requested by the OP.

Comment: I can't see the revision history for the question, but I don't think that the original version mentioned the Validate plugin. I could be wrong though...

Answer (score 9):

The above addMethod by Lod Lawson is not completely correct. It's $.validator and not $.validate and the validator method name cb_selectone requires quotes. Here is a corrected version that I tested:

```
$.validator.addMethod('cb_selectone', function(value,element){
    if(element.length>0){
        for(var i=0;i<element.length;i++){
            if($(element[i]).val('checked')) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}, 'Please select at least one option');
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the a quick solution for multiple checkbox validation using jquery validation plugin:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('atLeastOneChecked', function(value, element) {
  return ($('.cbgroup input:checked').length > 0);
});

$('#subscribeForm').validate({
  rules: {
    list0: { atLeastOneChecked: true }
  },
  messages: {
    list0: { 'Please check at least one option' }
  }
});

$('.cbgroup input').click(function() {
  $('#list0').valid();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (
  document.forms["form"]["mon"].checked==false &&
  document.forms["form"]["tues"].checked==false &&
  document.forms["form"]["wed"].checked==false &&
  document.forms["form"]["thrs"].checked==false &&
  document.forms["form"]["fri"].checked==false
) {
  alert("Select at least One Day into Five Days");
  return false; 
}
```

Comment: This is super nasty but I actually like the simplicity and zero-dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Good example without custom validate methods, but with metadata plugin and some extra html.

[Demo from Jquery.Validate plugin author](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$.validate.addMethod(cb_selectone,
                   function(value,element){
                           if(element.length>0){
                               for(var i=0;i<element.length;i++){
                                if($(element[i]).val('checked')) return true;
                               }
                           return false;
                           }
                            return false;
                  },
                  'Please select a least one')
```

Now you ca do

```
$.validate({rules:{checklist:"cb_selectone"}});
```

You can even go further a specify the minimum number to select with a third param in the callback function.I have not tested it yet so tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing and this is what I wrote.I made it more flexible in my case as I had multiple group of check boxes to check.

```
// param: reqNum number of checkboxes to select
$.fn.checkboxValidate = function(reqNum){
    var fields = this.serializeArray();
    return (fields.length < reqNum) ? 'invalid' : 'valid';
}
```

then you can pass this function to check multiple group of checkboxes with multiple rules.

```
// helper function to create error
function err(msg){
    alert("Please select a " + msg + " preference.");
}

$('#reg').submit(function(e){
    //needs at lease 2 checkboxes to be selected
    if($("input.region, input.music").checkboxValidate(2) == 'invalid'){
        err("Region and Music");
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slighlty different scenario. My checkboxes were created in dynamic and they were not of same group. But atleast any one of them had to be checked. My approach (never say this is perfect), I created a genric validator for all of them:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validatorName", function(value, element) {
    if (($('input:checkbox[name=chkBox1]:checked').val() == "Val1") ||
        ($('input:checkbox[name=chkBox2]:checked').val() == "Val2") ||
        ($('input:checkbox[name=chkBox3]:checked').val() == "Val3")) 
    {   
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }       
}, "Please Select any one value");
```

Now I had to associate each of the chkbox to this one single validator.

Again I had to trigger the validation when any of the checkboxes were clicked triggering the validator.

```
$('#piRequest input:checkbox[name=chkBox1]').click(function(e){
    $("#myform").valid();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked all answers and even in other similar questions, I tried to find optimal way with help of html class and custom rule.

my html structure for multiple checkboxes are like this

```js
$.validator.addMethod('multicheckbox_rule', function (value, element) {
   var $parent = $(element).closest('.checkbox_wrapper');
   if($parent.find('.checkbox_item').is(':checked')) return true;
            return false;
}, 'Please at least select one');
```

```html
<div class="checkbox_wrapper">
<label for="checkbox-1"><input class="checkbox_item" id="checkbox-1"  name="checkbox_item[1]" type="checkbox" value="1" data-rule-multicheckbox_rule="1" /> Checkbox_item 1</label>
<label for="checkbox-2"><input class="checkbox_item" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox_item[2]" type="checkbox" value="1" data-rule-multicheckbox_rule="1" /> Checkbox_item 1</label>
</div>
```