# Validate multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a script to show an alert if less than 10 checkboxes are checked
but I can’t get it to work.

I’ve reviewed many of the other similar posts but I can’t see what’s wrong.

This is the most similar to mine but I can’t see how to implement their suggestion:

[How to validate a form with multiple checkboxes to have atleast one checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535187/how-to-validate-a-form-with-multiple-checkboxes-to-have-atleast-one-checked)

Full code here:

https://github.com/bignellrp/footyapp

Script:

```js
function validate() {
  var checked = 0;
  //Reference the Table.
  var chks = document.getElementById("remember");

  //Loop and count the number of checked CheckBoxes.
  for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
    if (chks[i].checked) {
      checked++;
    }
  }

  if (checked > 9) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    alert("Dont you need 10 players?");
    return false;
  }
};
```

HTML (running in flask)

```html
<section class="projects-section bg-light" id="projects">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Featured Project Row-->
    <div class="row align-items-center no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5">
        <div class="featured-text text-center text-center">
          <form class="text-black-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5" method="POST" action="/">
            <table class="mx-auto text-lg-left" style="width: 40%">
              <colgroup>
                <col span="1" style="width: 10%;">
                <col span="1" style="width: 30%;">
              </colgroup>

              {% for name in player_names %}
              <tr>
                <td><input type=checkbox name="available_players" id="remember" value="{{ name }}"></td>
                <td>{{ name }}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
              <tr>
                <td><input type=checkbox name="output_checked" value="Yes"></td>
                <td>Admin Only</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger" type="submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML and will not work reliably, breaking your JavaScript; use class-names instead.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById will always give you only one element, but you refer to it as a collection. In order to get the collection of the checkboxes you need to give them all the same class name and then write your code like this:

```
var chks = document.getElementsByClassName("your_class_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that part of my problem seemed to be that the code i had in the script.js file wasnt inside the jquery end tag.  The second part was that id may not have been as reliable.  Instead of using class i've changed to using name as its a convenient way of applying the validation to a group that is already defined.

`var chks = $("input[name='available_players']:checked").length;`

https://github.com/bignellrp/footyapp/blob/main/static/scripts.js